# Modal - How to pass in correct variables to render within javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to pass in more than one variable to a render statement that will render the _form partial, using the following:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#contact_modal').click(function(event){
    $("#modal-window").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'contacts/form', new_contact: Contact.new ) %>");
```

I tried passing in two variables by doing the following:

```
new_contact: @contact, new_case: @case
```

but it doesn't seem to recognize the new_contact and new_case variables.  How do i pass in both of them and then use them in the simple_form_for?

EDIT:
I couldn't get it to work with the following setup (case has_many contacts):

routes.rb

```
resources :contacts

resources :cases do
  resources :contacts, :shallow => true
end
```

contacts_controller.rb

```
    def new
     if params[:case_id] 
      @case = Case.find(params[:case_id])
      @contact = @case.contacts.build
      @create_case_contacts_array = [@case, @contact]
     else
      @contact = Contact.new
      @create_case_contacts_array = @contact
     end
   end

   def create
    if params[:case_id] 
      @case = Case.find(params[:case_id])
      @contact = @case.contacts.build(params[:contact])
    else
      @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    end

    @contact.user = @user
    ...
   end
```

index.html.erb (where the modal is invoked)

```
 $("#modal-window").html("<%= escape_javascript( render :partial => "contacts/form", :locals => { :new_case => @case, :new_contact => @contact} ) %>");
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(new_case, new_contact) do |f| %> 
.
.
.
<%= f.button :submit %>
```

Why doesn't my cases/1/contacts page render (index of contacts)?  What am I doing wrong?  It has something to do with the index.html.erb line where i render the modal. I get the following error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue.

I just didn't pass in @contact through the index action in my contacts_controller.rb.  The new action really never gets invoked as I am invoking it manually through the modal that is within the index.html.erb file.

Answer (score 0):

```
 render :partial => "person", :locals => { :name => "david" ,:surname => "anderson"}
```

so this is how it works in your case:-

```
 $("#modal-window").html("<%= escape_javascript( render :partial => "contacts/form", :locals => { :new_contact => @contact ,:new_case => @case} ) %>");
```

now you can access `new_contact` and `new_case` in your form easily only if `@contact and @case are present`